# @NotNull integer parameter

Tags: java, rest, endpoint, java-ee-7

I created an endpoint, and I want to display a message if I don't fill a specific parameter.

For example:

```
 @NotNull(message = "The distance must be specified.") 
 @QueryParam("distance") 
 final double distance;
```

But for some reason I don't receive anything if I don't fill the field. Maybe because this is not a String?
How should I do?

Comment: For example, I want to call the endpoint from Postman. If I did not select the distance parameter there, I want to receive a message: "The distance must be specified."

Comment: No, is not working. But if I change it in Double instead of double it is ok.

Comment: Yes, double is a primitive data type. The default value is 0.0d when you don't pass this. This is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As double value can never be null, this never meets the criteria. If you try with a Wrapper class Double, then this should give your expected result.

```
@NotNull(message = "The distance must be specified.") 
@QueryParam("distance") 
final Double distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

`double` will always evaluate to `0` in case it doesn't exist, that's why `@NotNull` is not throwing an exception.

Use `Double` then if you don't send it, it will null.